# Arabic with Latin mathematical notation

Tags: symbols, align, arabic

I would like to write math formulas to look like the picture below:

[image]

I have the following segement of code, for example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\Roman{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}


\begin{document}


\begin{Arabic}
\begin{enumdescript}
   \item [\textbf{{\textarabic{محسن }}}]
    \
    \begin{itemize}
\item \textarabic{محسن محسن محسن محسن} \hfill $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{s} x^{i} & \textarabic{إذا كان} x <  0\\
\\
 \int\limits_{i=1}^{s} x^{i} dx & \textarabic{إذا كان} x > 0\\
\\
 \textrm{tg}(x) & {غير ذلك} (\pi\sim 3.141  \textarabic{مع} )\end{cases}$$

    \end{enumdescript}
\end{Arabic}
    \end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to switch to text mode:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\Roman{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}


\begin{document}


\begin{Arabic}
\begin{enumdescript}
\item [\textbf{{\textarabic{محسن }}}]\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textarabic{محسن محسن محسن محسن} \hfill
\[
f(x)=\begin{cases}
 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{s} x^{i} & \text{إذا كان}\quad x <  0\\
\\
 \int\limits_{i=1}^{s} x^{i} dx & \text{إذا كان}\quad x > 0\\
\\
 \operatorname{tg}(x) & \text{غير ذلك}\quad (\pi\sim 3.141\ \text{مع})
  \end{cases}
 \]
\end{itemize}
\end{enumdescript}
\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes. Don't use `$$`, but prefer `\[...\]`. Also the name of the tangent function should be the argument to `\operatorname`.

Comment: Since the whole paragraph is already inside `Arabic` environment, the `\textarabic` is superfluous.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I trust your word!